# jQuery Rails autocomplete gem, no response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem to try to complete a form. However, I'm just getting no response whatsoever.

Alright, here it goes:

In my view:

```
<%= form_tag chats_path do %>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'name', '', chats_autocomplete_chat_name_path %>
<% end %>
```

In my ChatsController:

```
  autocomplete :chat, :name
```

In my routes:

```
get "chats/autocomplete_chat_name"
```

And finally in my application.js:

```
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Although I'm sure the javascript is at least loading, since I put an alert to let me know that autocomplete-rails.js was loading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome -> tools -> developer tools and open up the "networking" tab. Then try again and see if you're form is being sent and if so, what the response is.

Comment: Ok. Opened up the networking tab, typed something into the form, don't see any response.

Comment: that means your form is not being submitted. try and see why it's not being submitted.

Comment: Shouldn't it not be submitted yet? Isn't that the point of autocomplete, that you can retrieve database results before submission?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular plugin but I don't see how it would know what to populate your values with until it hits the database. Anyway, you can also use chrome dev tools to debug your javascript. That's one place you could look

Comment: It does it through AJAX requests... that's autocomplete... Thanks for the advice, it just doesn't seem to be showing me anything that I can work with, other than that it's not making the requests

Comment: i took a quick look at the code. an ajax request from the gem would show a request to the web server. my guess is that things are just not setup right. try the detailed "active record" walkthrough they have.